# Two ID's linked in one table back to parent table. How do I display the name of both ID's?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I dont really know how to ask the question so I'll post my tables:

```
TBL_Airport
---------------
Airport ID (PK)
airportID (fk)
airportname

1
to
M

TBL_Route
--------------
Route ID (PK)
origin_airportID (child to airportID)
destination_airportID (child to airportID)
```

So I am looking to do a select statement that displays the two airport names beside the origin_airportID and destination_airportID. So far it is displaying the name of the first airport in the route but not the second. How do I differentiate between the airport name displayed in both as both origin and destination feed off the airportID

Many thanks,
P

Comment: join the table twice

Comment: I did that but there is a conflict between what i'm retrieving.

`SELECT passenger_age, airport_name, origin_airportID, airport_name, destination_airportID`

How do I differentiate the airport name to display dependant on the ID beside it.

Comment: Share a sample output, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Join the Route table with the Airport table twice - once for origin, once for destination, using "as" to differentiate between them in the result columns, and using table aliases to differentiate in the join.

Something like:

```
select R.Route_ID,
       A.airportname  as OriginAirportName,
       B.airportname  as DestinationAirportName
  from TBL_Route      R,
       TBL_Airport    A,
       TBL_Airport    B
 where R.origin_airportID      = A.Airport_ID
   and R.destination_airportID = B.Airport_ID
```

Comment: We tend to discourage pre-1992 style joins around here. Just sayin'.